# loading into 2d array from file in c++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble reading numbers from a file into a 2d array in c++.  It reads the first row just fine but the rest of the rows are populated with 0's.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int myarray[20][20];

    int totRow = 20, totCol = 20, number, product, topProduct = 0, row, col, count;
    char element[4];

    ifstream file;

    file.open( "c:\\2020.txt" );

    if( !file )
    {
        cout << "problem";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(255, '\n');
        cin.get();

        return 0;
    }

    while( file.good())
    {
        for( row = 0; row < totRow; row++ )
        {
            for( col = 0; col < totCol; col++ )
            {
                file.get( element, 4 );
                number = atoi( element );
                myarray[row][col] = number;
                cout << myarray[row][col] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;

        }
        file.close();
    }
```

Comment: what is the structure of 2020.txt ?

Comment: You could probably replace your entire `while` loop with `std::copy_n( std::istream_iterator<int>( file ), 20*20, &myarray[0][0] );`.

Comment: @trumpetlicks - No, that will work even if he has newlines. - http://ideone.com/u3Ww8P

Answer (score 3):

If there are only numbers in your file, you can just read them with the `>>` operator. Change your inner loop to:

```
for( col = 0; col < totCol; col++ )
{
    file >> myarray[row][col];
    cout << myarray[row][col] << " ";
}
```

The problem with `file.get()` is, it doesn't read beyond newline `\n`. See: [std::basic_istream::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)

Comment: @trumpetlicks No, this doesn't matter. The `>>` operator skips whitespace before reading the integer.

Comment: @trumpetlicks Look at [std::basic_istream::operator>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Answer (score 2):

You're closing the file inside the while loop:

```
while( file.good())
    {
        for( row = 0; row < totRow; row++ )
        {
            for( col = 0; col < totCol; col++ )
            {
                file.get( element, 4 );
                number = atoi( element );
                myarray[row][col] = number;
                cout << myarray[row][col] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;

        }
        file.close();   // <------ HERE
    } // end of while loop is here
```

You obviously can't read from a closed stream. Now, because you're trying to read all the data in the first iteration of the `while` loop, this doesn't seem to be your immediate problem. Note however, that the stream can still be `good()` even after you've read all the meaningful data (for example if there's a traling new-line character) and in that case, you'll enter the loop for the second time. That's a bug.

Comment: While not good form, Im not sure this is his ultimate problem.

Comment: @trumpetlicks My best guess, unless OP posts a sample input.

Comment: @jrok But outside the reading loop ;-) When the file is closed, he's already gone over the whole `myarray`.